# Asynchronous non-blocking remote logging in Java?

Tags: logging, asynchronous, log4j, java

Is there a lightweight logging framework/server I can use to setup remote logging in Java? I know log4j has SocketAppenders but a) I want a library that is more out of the box where I can simply run a log server, b) I want the logging calls to be completely asynchronous non-blocking from the rest of the code and c) A nice web based dashboard/viewer on the log-server would be also nice

Comment: http://java-source.net/open-source/logging  May be you can analyze here.

Answer (score 2):

[Apache Flume](http://incubator.apache.org/flume/) and [Apache Kafka](http://incubator.apache.org/kafka/) are two solutions that may be of use. I've seen them mentioned by the high scalability crowd a fair bit recently.

Neither is particularly similar to log4j, though.

Answer (score 2):

You could use log4j with a `SyslogAppender` and use some [tool](http://www.debianadmin.com/syslog-ng-web-interface-front-end-or-gui-tools.html) for viewing the syslog(-ng).
Use the async appender wrapper that ships with log4j, a nice article about that can be found [here](http://www.spartanjava.com/2009/asynchronous-logging-with-log4j/).