# asynchronous Logging to DB with GUI, java

Tags: java, performance, rest, logging

I would like to know any library which is light weight for asynchronous logging to database ,provide the flexibility of generating reports  and thread pool safe. We are a service provider(REST API's) and need to track the incoming traffic based on the source to provide weekly/monthly transaction report, which may include request/response.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9328891/asynchronous-non-blocking-remote-logging-in-java?rq=1

Comment: i checked this before posting this, was looking for "flexibility of generating reports" out of the same logging API/framework.

Comment: What do you mean by saying thread pool safe?